# iphone . is there a way to do that?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have an app that uses core data. The app is free for download and offers some options to buy. The in-app purchase options are based in the number of uses of a given function. The idea is to sell something like: $1 for 10 uses, $10 for 100 uses, etc.

But, I want to give the user one or two uses for free. My question is this: when the user first uses that function, I would mark it as used on core data, so, the next time, the user will have to buy more uses from the store, but suppose the user removes the app from the device after using it for the first time and reinstalls it from the cloud. Now the database is done, so, the flag I have saved after the first use. Now the user can use it again for free and will never pay anything.

Is there an option to prevent the user from doing this? I mean, saving the information on iCloud, for example? (yes, I know I can create my own server and force the users to register, but this is boring for the user... I am thinking about something inside iCloud or something).

Any thoughts? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may be interested in `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`.

Comment: AHA!!!! THAT'S IT! I knew I have read something about it, but I could not remember. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!